# How to iterate the elements using index in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just have an HTML page which contains only class attribute. Each class have individual table. I just wanna get the row count of each table.Since I have n number of table with same class name. Is it possible by using jquery?

I done something as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".testTable").each(function(index){

document.write(index); // It returns number of table in the page

});

});
```

Based on that code I just need to get the number of rows present in the each table. Just assume that the index returns as 3. I can assume that I have 3 table in that page. And I just wanna know how many rows present in each table. For example table1 :3 rows, and table2 :2 rows and table3 :5 rows as like that.

Is it possible? please help me to achieve this.

Also , I just wanna tell you that I don't have any id attribute for each table. I just want to do it by using only class attr not id.

Thanks in advanced.

-Sasi

Comment: This happens to be a question frequently asked on our site. Have you tried our on-site search? See [How do I search?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for help using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var checkStatus = function(elements){
        elements.each(function(){
            //check it contains the word
            if($(this).is(':contains("FAILED")')){
                //Empty the container and then add dynamic container
                $(this).empty();
                $(this).append('<div class="mainStatus">PASSED</div>');
            }
        })
    };
    $(".assertionTable").each(function(){
        checkStatus($(this).find("tr td:last-child"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find('tr')` selector to find rows in current table using table context `this` in `.each()` function. then use `.length` to get the length of returned rows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".testTable").each(function(index){
  console.log($(this).find('tr').length); // It returns number of rows in the current  table
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".testTable tr").each(function(index, tr){ // here tr is a dom element. so use $ to select tr like the below line

 console.log($(tr));  //here is your tr

});

});
```